# Adding resources to QML project results in very slow compilation

Tags: qt, resources, qml, qt-creator

I have added some icons to the resource file of my project and suddenly every tiny change to the QML code results in 7-8 seconds of wait time before the project is ran, it almost feels like it is recompiling the C++ code, but in reality that's the delay from the "compilation" of the qrc file.

I tried disabling qrc compression in hopes that it will get faster, but it didn't have any effect. This is very strange and annoying, considering the fact I am using a high end system with a fast CPU and SSD - the extra resources are only 2 megabytes, why is it taking so long? Adding the same files to an archive with high compression takes about 5 milliseconds.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, still no clue why is it so slow, but I found a way to avoid it.

The problem was that for every tiny change to QML sources the entire resource file was recompiled. So I moved all the images to another resource file, didn't have to do anything else, no need to change paths or anything, now QML code is in a different resource file and the one with the images is no longer recompiled on every change, so the project launches instantaneously.

Comment: I ran into this same issue and it was driving me nuts. I changed my project so the .qml files were read directly from the filesystem while developing and only used the qrc compiled versions for a release build. But I like your idea of separating the images (which change infrequently) from the QML files into two separate resource bundles. Why didn't I think of that!

Comment: I created two two qrc files under resource folder i.e. code.qrc and media.qrc. copied qml files in code.qrc and pngs in media.qrc but still its taking too much time compile and build program. What shoud I do ?

Comment: @taimoor1990 your project is probably configured to use the qt quick compiler, which is on by default. You should go to your building settings and disable the compiler, at least for the development phase, it is actually faster.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the compilation is slow is because all the resources others than QML files is converted and inserted into a big `uchar` array in the file `build.../[release/debug]/qrc_qml_qmlcache.cpp` and then compiled. Depending on the resource (like MP4) to be loaded faster, the resources are uncompressed which make the file even bigger and slower to compile. [For the alternative](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/resources.html#embedding-large-files)

Answer (score -1):

Qt's resources system will create a .cpp file that will contain an C++ array of compressed binary data of the files you put there so with 2MB of images + a your qml text file, qrc will have to regenerate a pretty big file that also takes time to compile.

More information [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html)

Comment: Pretty big? About 2 MB to be more precise. That's close to nothing. As I already mentioned, I disabled compression, so it is just all resource files serialized into a single binary as raw byte arrays. It certainly doesn't explain why it is so slow. 8 seconds on a system with 4.3 Ghz iyv bridge CPU, 32 gigs of ram and a 500+ mb/sec ssd, that has got to be some record in terms of code inefficiency.