# How to add the path of images in a QML project correctly

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols2

I'm going to practice [this example](https://qmlbook.github.io/en/ch01/index.html#digesting-an-user-interface) and for that I created a *Qt Quick Console 2 Application* project named *Main2* using Qt *Creator 4.3.0* on a windows 7 machine.

The code for *main.qml* looks like this:
[image: like this] and I get the following errors in the *Application Output* window:

> The program has unexpectedly finished.
>   C:\Users\Abbasi\Documents\QML\Main2\Main2\build-Main2-Desktop_Qt_5_9_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\Main2.exe crashed.
>   Starting C:\Users\Abbasi\Documents\QML\Main2\Main2\build-Main2-Desktop_Qt_5_9_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\Main2.exe...
>   QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.

What is the problem with the paths or anything please?

The images are in a folder named *images* on the Desktop. How to move them to a folder under the project, a step-by-step means please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- copy the images folder to your project folder
- right click on your project - add new - Qt - resource file - `images.qrc`
- right click on that - add existing files, goto /images and select what you want to add
- alternatively, you can directly use the "add existing directory" option to add all files in a directory

Then from QML you simply:

```
Image { source: "images/whatever.jpg" }
```

This way the images are neatly packed inside your executable. Which is OK in most cases, unless you have gigabytes of images. It also helps prevent people replacing your stock images with profane versions ;)

Creating a separate resource file for images will [do wonders for your build times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35092171/adding-resources-to-qml-project-results-in-very-slow-compilation).

If you are that keen on file system access, be that absolute (please don't do that **ever** in production) or relative, you will have to prepend a `file://` to the path to tell Qt you want the file system rather than internal resources.

Update: As revealed by your `main.cpp` file, **the actual problem is you are using a project template that uses `QQmlApplicationEngine`. The tutorial you are following dates back to the days before that, and uses `QQuickView`**. The latter can have any QML element as a root, but the former needs to have an `ApplicationWindow`, which is the reason you are not getting any output. So you need to wrap your existing code in an `ApplicationWindow`:

```
ApplicationWindow {
  visible: true
  width: 640
  height: 480

  // your code goes here
}
```

Comment: Why shall you not use `file:/` in production (besides that it is recommended to use a `QImageProvider`)? It makes it easier to add user pictures.

Comment: The warning was against using absolute paths, not external images.

Comment: Ah I see. That's for sure!

Comment: I copied the *images* folder into the project folder and used an *images.qrc* file [like this](https://s3.postimg.org/72o9g6ioj/image.png) and ran the app using that prefix name. It says it [cannot open](https://s4.postimg.org/fj9erhn8d/image.png) the files! What is the problem please? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Ops, I misled you, since you already have the folder you don't need the prefix. Try it without the prefix, you can right click on the qrc file - open with - plain text editor and simply change the prefix to `<qresource prefix="/">`

Comment: Thank you for the guide, I did it. First changing [the prefix](https://s4.postimg.org/tskgbbyf1/image.png) then changing the code. Bu it still [shows errors](https://s4.postimg.org/ngqtrzvbh/image.png)! :(

Comment: Use `"images/image.png"` as your source. A subdirectory in the qrc is very similar to having a prefix.

Comment: I use it and works without errors. But it [shows nothing](https://s2.postimg.org/oonx16rjd/Capture.png). :(

Comment: This is strange, it should work like it is on that image. Maybe your build has frozen and can't update, try Build - Run qmake from the creator menu and give it another go.

Comment: The example is from [here](https://qmlbook.github.io/en/ch01/index.html#digesting-an-user-interface). I may have gone through some minor wrong way. Would you create the project as I did? Whatever I do it shows nothing! :-(

Comment: Just as I though, I will update the answer in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

use qrc: with image URL might work

```
 Image { source: "qrc:images/whatever.jpg" }
```